# develop "custom maps" offine no roaming charge

Tags: android, gps

Firstly I am new to the site and new to android development

I want to design a tour of a local town that would run on android mobile phone. Its a historical tour so I want to to use my own custom map to represent the period and use GPS to figure out where the person is.

As it is for tourists who more than likely are roaming I do not want to connect to the internet. I have figured out that this rules Google maps and overlaying a customer map on it.

I'd be very grateful if someone could direct me to an alternative solution. A few pointers to put me on the right path would be great

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out [Osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) which is a map library for [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) data.  if you really want your own custom map then it is possible with osmdroid but I have no experiance of it.  A simpler solution would be to use the OSM data and contribute any updated you need to the map of your area to get it good enough for you.  You do have the option of having static map data with Osmdroid so you can use it ofline.

There are a number of other libraries but Osmdroid is the one I use and am farmiliar with.

Answer (score 0):

When using Eclipse, in the DDMS perspective, make sure the correct device (propably emulator-any ) is selected and highlighted. Only then will you get the logcat output in the logcat view.

Also, the Android plugin is a bit quircky, and sometimes only shows the last line in the logcat view. If this happens, try to clear the log. After that, you should get all the log entries again